# Can an Exclusion Script (for domain exclusion) be applied to Transactional Messaging API sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am working with a dev team that wants to start testing sends via Transactional Messaging API. How would others recommend applying domain exclusion in that context? My original plan was to apply as an exclusion script but there is no equivalent of a triggered send definition that I can see to apply the script to in the UI. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the '[Create Send Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm)' there is not an option of an exclusion/suppression list. You would need to design a process to exclude the subscriber before you made the api call to send the email.

Comment: Thanks @eazyE! A bit of a bummer but 'tis what it 'tis.